# Decorator not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my decorator working but I keep getting returned with

```
TypeError: command() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm not sure what is happening, is someone able to explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

**Decorator Code**

```
def command(command):
    def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return command(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return method
```

**Function using Decorator**

```
@bot.command
async def speak(msg : str):
    await bot.say(msg)
```

**Demonstration**

I would like to have a bot that'll react to commands on a trigger.

For example, I'll send a chat message:

```
?eval 1 * 2
```

which the bot will reply with

```
2
```

By using the `@bot.command`, I'll be able to create a flexible system which tells the application that the function is a command on-trigger.

e.g

```
@bot.command
async def eval(self, *args)
    await bot.send(eval(*args))
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - what is `bot`, for example? Where's the rest of the traceback?

Comment: I'll show you something which demonstrates what I'm trying to do. @jonrsharpe

Comment: That edit doesn't help at all. Please re-read the linked help center article, and provide something that **actually helps recreate the issue**. We should ideally be able to cut and paste something, execute it and see exactly the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are decorating with `bot.command`.

If `bot` is an object, then `bot.command` is a method and is called with a `self` parameter before the `command` argument, hence the “2 were given”.

Comment: So what are you saying then? Should I add or remove `self` to `command()` function?

Comment: @stat.us well why is `bot.command` an instance method? It doesn't use any `self` state, why not make it a `@staticmethod` (or remove it from the class altogether)? Or is `bot` a module?

Comment: Because I wanted to build a decorator class for my Discord bot, so I want to keep my code clean.

Comment: So the class is a namespace. Just use `@staticmethod` before `def command`, then.

Comment: Thanks dude, @ValentinLorentz! you're awesome.